# Lista de objetos do JS no Controller C# MVC não aparece no Request.Cookies

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-core, cookies, .net-core

Estou colocando o seguinte Cookie:

```
document.cookie = "Teste=" + '[{"Id":20,"Nome":"Prato Feito","Valor":12.5,"Quantidade":1,"Imagem":"/images/ImgEmpty/noImg.jpg","Descricao":"Batata Palha, Cebola, Tomate"}]';
```

ele aparece na lista de Cookies no navegador:
[image: Cookie Teste]

Consigo utilizar o Cookie no JS para fazer o que quiser... Porém quando vou tentar achar ele no controller, não aparece na lista de Cookies:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que devo fazer?
Percebi se tiver 'espaços' no cookie acontece mesma coisa:

```
document.cookie = "Teste=Hello World"
```

mas se fizer:

```
document.cookie = "Teste=HelloWorld", já aparece ja lista dos cookies no controller.
```

Answer (score 0):

Galera conseguir solucionar onde eu usava para add cookie só coloquei

> encodeURIComponent

```
document.cookie = 'Nome=' + encodeURIComponent((JSON.stringify(produtos)));
```

e para leitura

> decodeURIComponent

Pego o cookie pelo nome depois uso 'decodeURIComponent':

```
var cookieValue = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)Nome\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
var dec = decodeURIComponent(cookieValue);
```